# Как правильно организовать экспорт в Excel в Spring-MVC

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-mvc, apache-poi

Добрый день.
Есть контроллер в котором есть метод поиска.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(@RequestParam Integer idProvider, @RequestParam String department,
        @RequestParam String carNumber,
        @RequestParam("arrivalDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
        @RequestParam("arrivalDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate,
        @ModelAttribute("idAttribute") Supply supply, Model model) throws DaoException {

    List<Supply> supplyList = supplyDao.searchByCriteria(idProvider, department, carNumber, startDate, endDate);
    model.addAttribute("supplyList", supplyList);

    return "searchList";
```

Данный метод выводит результаты поиска на JSP страницу.
Как правильно организовать экспорт этих данных в Excel?

Я создал класс для создание документа:

```
    public class ExcelBuilder extends AbstractXlsxView {

private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

@Override
protected void buildExcelDocument(Map model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // change the file name
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    LinkedList<Supply> supplyes = (LinkedList<Supply>) model.get("supplyList");

    // create excel xls sheet
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Отчет");

    // create header row
    Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Дата поставки");
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue("Номер автомобиля");
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Фамилия водителя");
    header.createCell(3).setCellValue("Телефон");
    header.createCell(4).setCellValue("Отдел");
    header.createCell(5).setCellValue("Товар");
    header.createCell(6).setCellValue("Документ поставщика");
    header.createCell(7).setCellValue("Документ получателя");
    header.createCell(8).setCellValue("Кладовщик");
    header.createCell(9).setCellValue("Диспетчер");

    // Create data cells
    int rowCount = 1;
    for (Supply supply : supplyes) {
        Row supplyRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
        supplyRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(DATE_FORMAT.format(supply.getArrivalDate()));
        supplyRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(supply.getCarNumber());
        supplyRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(supply.getDriverName());
        supplyRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(supply.getPhone());
        supplyRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(supply.getDepartment());
        supplyRow.createCell(5).setCellValue(supply.getProduct());
        supplyRow.createCell(6).setCellValue(supply.getVendorDocument());
        supplyRow.createCell(7).setCellValue(supply.getDocumentReceiving());
        supplyRow.createCell(8).setCellValue(supply.getStorekeeper());
        supplyRow.createCell(9).setCellValue(supply.getDispatcher());

    }

}
```

}

Далее создал метод в контроллере:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  ModelAndView downloadExcel(@ModelAttribute("supplyList") Supply supply) {
    //return new ModelAndView("excelView2");        
}
```

Насколько я понял для экспорта в Excel можно использовать только ModelAndView.

Вопрос: как передать данные из supplyList в новую модель для сохранения в Excel?

Посоветуйте как лучше сделать? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому пригодится. Вопрос решил следующим образом:
Атрибут передал из контроллера в контроллер с помощью  HttpServletRequest:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(@RequestParam Integer idProvider, @RequestParam String department,
        @RequestParam String carNumber,
        @RequestParam("arrivalDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
        @RequestParam("arrivalDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate,
        @ModelAttribute("idAttribute") Supply supply, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws DaoException {
    List<Supply> supplyList = supplyDao.searchByCriteria(idProvider, department, carNumber, startDate, endDate);
    model.addAttribute("supplyList", supplyList);

    request.getSession().setAttribute("supplyList", supplyList);

    return "searchList";
```

И второй контроллер который принял атрибут:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView downloadExcel(@ModelAttribute("supplyList") Supply supply, HttpServletRequest request) {

    List<Supply> list = (List<Supply>) request.getSession().getAttribute("supplyList");

    return new ModelAndView("excelView2", "supplyList", list);
```

Далее создал файл views.properties в папке src/main/resources. Содержимое файла:

```
    excelView2.(class)=dispatcher.exportToExcel.ExcelBuilder
    pdfView.(class)=dispatcher.report.PdfBuilder
```

Вот и все.

Такая- же процедура и при экспорте в Pdf.