# Сделать динамически формируемый отчет в excel

Tags: java, spring, excel

Нужно сделать отчет в excel, который бы загружался по клику на ссылку, использую Spring MVC и JExcel Api. При клике по линку контроллер отлавливает переход и метод формирования отчета в сервисе запускается, однако, в результате в браузере ничего не происходит. Что не так?

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView generateScheduleReport(HttpServletResponse response) {
  reportService.createExcelOutputExcel(response);
  return null;
}
```

Сервис:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class ReportService implements ExcelOutputService{

public WritableWorkbook createExcelOutputExcel(HttpServletResponse response) {
    String fileName = "Excel_Output.xls";
    WritableWorkbook writableWorkbook = null;
    try {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

        writableWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(response.getOutputStream());

        WritableSheet excelOutputsheet = writableWorkbook.createSheet("Excel Output", 0);
        addExcelOutputHeader(excelOutputsheet);
        writeExcelOutputData(excelOutputsheet);

        writableWorkbook.write();
        writableWorkbook.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occured while creating Excel file", e);
    }

    return writableWorkbook;
}
...
}
```

Comment: возвращается по идее через http response

Comment: может это поможет: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610071/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B2-excel-%D0%B2-spring-mvc/615151

Comment: Конкретно в контроллере вы не возвращаете уже созданный файл, используйте try/catch блок непосредственно в апи контроллера, и при удачном прохождение в finaly возвращайте ссылку на файл